# Running both PHP and Node.js on Nginx(php extension file for PHP, html extension for node)

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, nginx

Good day, i want handle php file and html on same server, i want that html files handle node on port 8080, and php files handle php5 service. I wrote nginx config like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /home/examle/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.examle.com examle.com;

    location ~ \.html$ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

but when html pages opened nodejs didn't handle node javascript which contains in html page. How can i handle both type of files php and html on same server?

Comment: And what happens when you open sample.html ? 404 ?

Comment: page opened but node didn't handle javascript at all, if open example.com:8080/sample.html page displayed perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

It won't work this way.

The thing is: when you use `nginx`+`php`, `nginx` doesn't really run `php filename.php` when you hit `localhost/filename.php`. There is [php-fpm](http://php-fpm.org/) and nginx sends request to it. Then, `php-fpm` runs actual script, creating proper `$_SERVER`, `$_GET`, etc.

In `node` case, you don't have any `node-fpm` service. Nginx won't run `node filename.html`. You need to set up the real node process at 8080 port that serves http connections, because all `nginx` does is it "passes" an actual http connection to the `http://localhost:8080`, as you specified.

Learn how to get node http server working.

P.S. Clue: look at your nginx logs more often (`/var/log/nginx/*` at Ubuntu/Debian). :)

Comment: Solved, solution you can find here: https://github.com/fastogt/siteonyourdevice/blob/master/node/server_details.html . Nginx work as needed but when starting load javascript sources cannot find it(i found it in browser debug mode "Reference io not defined") after that i specify where needed search javascript sources <script src="http://siteonyourdevice.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> and after that the page start loading in the right way.